# Scrollview not working properly on iPad in xcode(iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, uiscrollview

Recently, i've been building and app which requires a scrollview, for all the content to fit. I've had a few difficulties creating my scrollview. I've tried a few different methods for building it, but ended up building it in storyboard with autolayout. I've set the height of the view controller to 1000, and therefore also the simulated size to freeform. The width of the content view inside the scrollview, I've to the same as the view which contains the scrollview.

The hierarchy goes like this:

1. -View controller scene
2. -Top layout guide
3. -Bottom layout guide
4. -View
5. -Scroll view
6. -Content view
7. -Label with text here
8. -Constraints
9. -And so on

I've been replicating the process in this link, to create the scrollview:
https://www.ralfebert.de/snippets/ios/auto-layout-recipes/uiscrollview-storyboard/

When running the application on the simulator, I get the following result:
The scrollview is not working properly on the iPad. It seems like the scrollview doesn't adapt to the changes in the width, which happens when its ran on an iPad, since it's bigger. When the app is ran on the iPad, the scrollview stays the same width as if it were shown on the iPhone.

This is how it looks in the editor. The view controller on the left is the view controller which has the scrollview implemented, and the one on the right doesn't. The first image shows the storyboard, when I view it with the iPhone 8, and the second image is when I view it with an 9,7" iPad:
[image: iPhone 8]

[image: iPad 9,7"]

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could give me a hint to whats going on!

**EDIT:**
Left side is what it looks like, and right side is what it should look like:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is that you're referring to? What do you want it to look like? What does it look like? Can you show a screenshot of the setup of your view. The hierarchy bit

Comment: Two ideas. First: you have messed with auto layout constrains. Second: looks like you have the textView centered vertically inside the UIView in the UIScrollView.

Comment: @Fogmeister I posted an image down at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the `UIScrollView` to your main view
2. Set Top, Left, Right, Bottom constraints all to Zero
3. Add a `UILabel` inside the scroll view
4. Set number of lines to Zero
5. Set Top, Left, Right, Bottom constraints all to Zero
6. Set the label's width constraint equal to the scroll view's width

That should do it :)

This will keep the label's text aligned to the top of the scroll view. If you add enough text to fill more than the full screen, it will scroll vertically.